# Google Drive API for iOS: OAuth2.0 with an application-owned account

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm creating a simple iPhone app. The basic premise is that the app will display some data (That I provide online) on the application. The data changes over time, so the app has to draw the data from online and display it. I don't have a significant programming background so I don't want to use my own server.

Thus, I thought it would be significantly easier to just put the data into some documents on a Google account and then access them programmatically via the Google Drive API. I could then update the data in my Drive account and it would get updated in the application. The key here is that I am ONLY accessing ONE account that I own MYSELF. The users' accounts are not being accessed. Therefore the goal is to never have to log in manually. It should all happen behind the scenes, aka, it should look like a server, not a google doc.

With this in mind, it doesn't make sense to show the Google Accounts sign-in page to my users as the standard OAuth2.0 tutorial shows here:https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios#step_1_enable_the_drive_api

I should be able to access my own data by somehow hardcoding in my username, password etc. Google agrees here: https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts#use_regular_google_accounts_as_application-owned_accounts

The above link mentions a "refresh token" that I'm supposed to save. However, I have no idea how to build and save that token, or even for that matter, where to find it.

I've gone through both the basic tutorial and the Dr. Edit Tutorial for iOS, but they both assume that the application is accessing USER accounts not application-owned accounts.

I'm not asking for someone to write the code for me (though tidbits are nice), but if you can point me to a step-by-step guide or related sample code that would help me get started that would be awesome. I'll even come back and post the code that I use!

EDIT: Since I realized that the Google Drive API wasn't something I could use for what I am trying to do, I eventually found [Parse](http://www.parse.com) which is an awesome tool that handles all the server backend for me and is free at the basic level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google APIs objective-C client library doesn't support service (application-owned) accounts, because they are supposed to be used by a server-side apps, instead of clients -- you shouldn't be distributing your private key as a part of an app.

If you would like to distribute content from a service account, maybe you should write a server leg to do the authentication and pass clients credentials in a secure way for them to talk to the API on the behalf of the service account. Or, use [Web publishing](https://developers.google.com/drive/publish-site) to make documents universally accessible without authorization and authentication if privacy is not a concern.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts#use_regular_google_accounts_as_application-owned_accounts

this seems to contradict that. Can you explain further?

Comment: Thanks, I eventually figured it out and decided to use a different solution. See edit for details.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to authenticated as an [installed iOS application](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/?hl=en_US#installedapplications) and thereby achieve a flow similar to the use of a service account but without the need to place such a credential on the client?